# Writing a list of Integers to a .Bin file in Python 2.7 using bytearray() causes 10 to be converted to New line character and writes as 0x14 and 0x10

Tags: python, arrays, hex, bin

My integer list is `A = [14,10,0,0]`;

```
f.write(bytearray(A))
```

My binary file (Viewed as a HEX shows)

```
0e 0d 0a 00 00
```

Notice the additional `0d` that comes before the `0a`

Answer (score 0):

Python interprets the number 10 in byte representation as a newline character, more precisely an ASCII Linefeed (LF):

```
In [1]: A = [14,10,0,0]

In [2]: bytearray(A)
Out[2]: bytearray(b'\x0e\n\x00\x00')
```

Are you by any chance using Windows? There, a newline is written to a file as a sequence of a Carriage Return (CR, 0d in hexadecimal) and a Line Feed character. To avoid this system-dependent translation you should open the file in [binary mode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

> If mode is omitted, it defaults to 'r'. The default is to use text mode, which may convert '\n' characters to a platform-specific representation on writing and back on reading. Thus, when opening a binary file, you should append 'b' to the mode value to open the file in binary mode, which will improve portability.

Comment: Yup. On a Windows 10. I am actually opening the file as a HEX. Thats where the actual problem is. It is meant to be 10 in hex. But it splits into two hex numbers for some reason